# Creating manual threads - but getting duplicate threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, duplicates

ISSUE: Getting duplicate items, i.e more threads are getting created than the array size... 
Hi Folks, I am creating thread in the loop for each element of array. The real use is that the of sending a batch of messages using amazon ses. the messages are stored in the messageamazonRequestBatch and the loop runs through the batch and sends the messages.

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
Thread thrdSendEmail;
            try
            {
                string amazonMessageID = string.Empty;
                List<Thread> lstThread = new List<Thread>();
                foreach (int n in arrMessageid)
                {
                    thrdSendEmail = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).req);
                                messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).msg.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                                logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n , true);
                                //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n + ",\t" + messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).msg.QueueMessageId + ",\t" + amazonMessageID, true);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true); }                                
                    });
                    thrdSendEmail.Name = n.ToString();
                    lstThread.Add(thrdSendEmail);
                    thrdSendEmail.Start();
                    //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n, true);
                }
                foreach (Thread t in lstThread)
                {
                    t.Join();
                    //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + t.Name, true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true);
            }
```

I have also tried parallel.foreach and asynch and await options... they also give the duplicates. I know that the lock will solve the problem but in my case the lock degrades the performance by a factor of 10.. that is my performance drops 10 times... coz putting the sendemail login in lock is blocking untill i get a return amazonmessageid from amazon...

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. I am not a novice programmer but new to threading...

Comment: Are you using C# 5 or an earlier version?

Comment: c# 4.0 --> Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01018-532-2002102-70050

Answer (score 3):

Your lambda expression is capturing the loop variable `n`, so when your lambda executes, the value of `n` has already changed; you need to copy `n` to a local variable inside the loop. (assuming you're using C# 4 or earlier; C# 5 fixed that problem).

Another issue is that all your threads use the same `amazonMessageID` variable; you should declare it inside the lambda expression instead.

```
            foreach (int n in arrMessageid)
            {
                int n2 = n;
                thrdSendEmail = new Thread(() =>
                {
                        try
                        {
                            string amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n2).req);
                            messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n2).msg.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                            logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n2 , true);
                            //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n2 + ",\t" + messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n2).msg.QueueMessageId + ",\t" + amazonMessageID, true);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true); }                                
                });
 ...
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your suggestion but that still gives me duplicates..

Comment: Hi Thomas, The proof of concept i did for this also gives me duplicate.  ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
            {
                return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            }); Action action = () =>
            {bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;
                logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" , true);};Parallel.Invoke(action);

Comment: @user3241488, OK, what do you mean *exactly* by "duplicates" ? Does it send the same message several times? And are you sure that arrMessageid contains only distinct values? And what are you trying to do with ThreadLocal? The code you posted in your comment makes no sense at all and doesn't do anything useful...

Comment: Yes it sends some of the messages serveral times for example if i send 50000 messages than i receive 500-1000 duplicate messages. So the code i posted is just a proof of concept.. this threadlocal has to send a individual message and wait for the amazon response which i will update in my database.

Comment: u can look also at my complete code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419904/creating-manual-threads-also-tried-using-parallel-foreach-and-async-await-but/21419905?noredirect=1#comment32322920_21419905

Comment: Hi Thomas, the below code also gives me duplicate, however if I apply lock, i get perfect results without duplicate...  i dont want to lock my entire code in thread or in parallel.foreach loop coz my performance degrades 10 times...
if you look into the above code and if i commented SendSimpleEmail_Part2(messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n2).req);.. still i get duplicates... if i apply lock then each thread waits and my performance degrades.. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Guys, i have created a new thread and posted amazon reply on duplicate issue and along with my changed code in the new thread --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556162/further-on-creating-manual-threads-but-getting-duplicate-threads

Answer (score 0):

I don't like that your threads share the same variables (I mean `n` and `amazonMessageID`), it is not thread safe and it may cause your problem. Moreover I suggest you to use [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd992001%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, it can make your code easy. It could look like this:

```
try
{

     Parallel.ForEach(arrMessageid.Distinct(),
         n => 
         {
             try
             {
                 var amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).req);
                 messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).msg.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                 logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n , true);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true); 
             }
         }
      );              

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tony, I have also tried to implement your suggestion but it is still giving me duplicates. However i have not used as distinct as it gives me the error Error 31 The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Action<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Hi Tony, I figures out how to use distinct **(Parallel.ForEach(messageAmazonRequestBatch.Distinct<Message_withRequest>(),) but with this also it gives me duplicate... so if i run the batch for 4000 i get somewhere between 200-500 duplicates..

Comment: @user3241488 Hm, what is the type of `arrMessageid`? In your code you use `foreach(int n in arrMessageid)`, shouldn't it be some kind of `IEnumerable<int>` ?

Comment: arrMessageid was a simple array of integer which was holding the index position of messages. However i have tried this code with list and concurentbag objects as well.

Comment: Ah, ok, but why I trying to pass to Parallel.ForEach `messageAmazonRequestBatch` and not `arrMessageid.Distinct()` ?

Comment: This also doesnt work...Parallel.ForEach(arrMessageid.Distinct<int>(),
                        n =>
                        {

                                int n2 = n;
                                var amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n2).req);}

Comment: You mean there is a error message? If not and there still exists duplicates, it means that `messageAmazonRequestBatch` contains them.

Comment: Hi Tony, there is no error but the duplicate still exists and also i verified that messageAmazonRequestBatch does not have duplicates.. The same issue happens if i use array of message index instead of messageAmazonRequestBatch... So i feel that the compiler is creating more threads somehow...

Comment: I don't think so :) I believe that in this case error in some other code. It's hard to say what is wrong, so debugging is needed to see what caused that.

Comment: Hi Tony, for debugging i have written everything in logs.. IF I apply lock, i get perfect results without duplicate... But i am getting duplicate without locks.. Not only is this happening in my scenario but the proof of concept i ran independently also cause this issue.. So here my scenario is i dont want to lock my entire code in thread or in parallel.foreach loop...

Comment: That's important information! I guess some of your code is not thread safe, and I guess it is `SendSimpleEmail_Part2` method. Could you provide its code?

Comment: Sure... Here it is...         private string SendSimpleEmail_Part2(SendEmailRequest request)//ASH-TEST 11Jan14
        {
           
                try
                {
                    return ses.SendEmail(request).SendEmailResult.MessageId;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logManager_RunSummary.LogException(ex);//ash17sep2013
                    throw ex;//ash17sep2013
                }
        }

Comment: It is used some another class :) I think this class caused the problem, but I don't think it is possible to find this out using comments :)

Comment: Hi Tony, Even if i comment out the  return ses.SendEmail(request).SendEmailResult.MessageId; and return null; instead than also i am getting duplicate so it is not related to any specific function i am afraid...

Comment: u can look also at my complete code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419904/creating-manual-threads-also-tried-using-parallel-foreach-and-async-await-but/21419905?noredirect=1#comment32322920_21419905