# Creating manual threads, also tried using parallel.foreach and async await - but getting duplicate

Tags: c#, multithreading

ISSUE: Getting duplicate items, i.e more threads are getting created than the array size... 
Hi Folks, I am creating thread in the loop for each element of array. The real use is that the of sending a batch of messages using amazon ses. the messages are stored in the messageamazonRequestBatch and the loop runs through the batch and sends the messages.

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
Thread thrdSendEmail;
            try
            {
                string amazonMessageID = string.Empty;
                List<Thread> lstThread = new List<Thread>();
                foreach (int n in arrMessageid)
                {
                    thrdSendEmail = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).req);
                                messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).msg.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                                logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n , true);
                                //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n + ",\t" + messageAmazonRequestBatch.ElementAt(n).msg.QueueMessageId + ",\t" + amazonMessageID, true);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true); }                                
                    });
                    thrdSendEmail.Name = n.ToString();
                    lstThread.Add(thrdSendEmail);
                    thrdSendEmail.Start();
                    //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + n, true);
                }
                foreach (Thread t in lstThread)
                {
                    t.Join();
                    //logManager_MessageLogwithAmazonmsgID.LogMessage(",\t" + t.Name, true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logManager_RunSummary.LogMessage(ex.Message, true);
            }
```

I have also tried parallel.foreach and asynch and await options... they also give the duplicates. I know that the lock will solve the problem but in my case the lock degrades the performance by a factor of 10.. that is my performance drops 10 times... coz putting the sendemail login in lock is blocking untill i get a return amazonmessageid from amazon...

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. I am not a novice programmer but new to threading.

ALSO TRIED MANY VERSION OF PARALLEL.foreach

```
private int SendEmailTask_Ver9_23Jan()//tried to create manual threads in parallel foreach and called SendSimpleEmail_Part3 but still duplicates
    {
        activeThreadCount++; threadCount++;
        IList<Airmail.Core.Message> messageBatch = null;
        lock (dbLocker)
        {
            if (activeThreadCount > maxNoofTaskCount)//targetThreadCount
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (abort)
            {
                sendComplete = true;
                return 0;
            }
            try
            {
                messageBatch = messageRepository.ash_GetNextBatch_AirmailVer2(maxBatchSize, this.senderTrackingHost);//messageBatch = messageRepository.ash_GetNextBatch(maxBatchSize);                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logManager_RunSummary.LogException(ex);
                messageBatch = new List<Airmail.Core.Message>();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(this.currentStatus);
        }
        while (messageBatch != null && messageBatch.Count != 0)
        {
            IDictionary<Airmail.Core.Message, MessageHistory> toUpdate = new Dictionary<Airmail.Core.Message, MessageHistory>();
            batchSize = messageBatch.Count;
            sendComplete = false;
            //foreach (Airmail.Core.Message message in messageBatch)                
            logManager_CollectionLog.LogMessage("\tBatch\t-\t" + messageBatch.Count + "\t-\t" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, true);//ASH-TEST 11Jan14
            int intCounter = 0;//ash-teset 11han14
            System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<Airmail.Core.Message> messageBatchConcurrent = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<Airmail.Core.Message>(messageBatch);
            //All public and protected members of ConcurrentBag<T> are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.
            //foreach (Airmail.Core.Message message in messageBatchConcurrent)
            Parallel.ForEach(messageBatchConcurrent, message =>                
            {
                //messageBatchConcurrent.Where(x => x == message).Take(1);//ash12Jan14
                lock (statLocker)
                {
                    //messageBatchConcurrent.TryTake(out message);
                    totalProcessed++;
                    intCounter += 1;//ASH-TEST 10Jan14                    
                    message.ash_BatchLoopCounter = intCounter.ToString();
                    //message.ash_BatchSizeCount = messageBatchConcurrent.Count.ToString();
                }
                if (message.ExpiryDate < DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                    toUpdate.Add(message, message.UpdateStatus(MessageStatus.Expired, "", null, null, true));
                    //message.continue(); //continue;//continue will just skip the current iteration.
                    return; //using return instead of continue as --> (the body is just a function called for each item)
                }

                lock (statLocker)
                {
                    StatisticKey key = new StatisticKey(Convert.ToInt32(message.ash_campaignHistoryID), Convert.ToInt32(message.ash_campaignTemplateID), message.Status);//ASH25,OCT13//Airmail 2.0 changes
                    if (!statistics.ContainsKey(key)) statistics.Add(key, 0);
                    statistics[key]--;
                }
                try
                {

                    string amazonMessageID = string.Empty;
                    if (message.Attachments == null || message.Attachments == "")//ASH25,OCT13//Airmail 2.0 changes
                    {
                        //test//if (intCounter > 1000) { Debugger.Break(); }
                        SendEmailResponse response = null;
                        if (message.ash_isSent == "YES") { return; }
                        //if (message.ash_isSent == null) { response = SendSimpleEmail(ref message, message.QueueMessageId, message.ash_BatchLoopCounter + "-" + message.ash_BatchSizeCount, message.ash_isSent); }//ASH-TEST 11Jan14                           
                        /// Start - this is parallel.invoke testing on 23Jan14
                        try
                        {
                            //Parallel.Invoke(
                            //    delegate()        // Param #2 - in-line delegate
                            //    {
                            //mReq.msg.AmazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2((SendEmailRequest)mReq.req);
                            //logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage(",\t" + mReq.msg.QueueMessageId, true);
                            //    }
                            //);
                            //intthreadCount++;
                            //logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage(",\t creating new thread", true);
                            Thread thrdSendEmail = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                if (message.ash_isSent == null) { response = SendSimpleEmail_Part3(message, message.QueueMessageId, message.ash_BatchLoopCounter + "-" + message.ash_BatchSizeCount, message.ash_isSent); }
                            });
                            lock (statLocker)
                            {
                                thrdSendEmail.Start();                                    
                            }
                            thrdSendEmail.Join();
                            //logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage(",\t finishing new thread", true);
                        }
                        // No exception is expected in this example, but if one is still thrown from a task, 
                        // it will be wrapped in AggregateException and propagated to the main thread. 
                        catch (AggregateException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("An action has thrown an exception. THIS WAS UNEXPECTED.\n{0}", e.InnerException.ToString());
                        }
                        /// End -   this is parallel.invoke testing on 23Jan14                            
                        //SendRawEmailResponse response = SendRawEmail(message);

                        //cSH12Jan14-test//sqlLogSentMessage += "EXEC ash_Log_SentMessageids  " + "@MessageID = " + message.QueueMessageId + ", " + "@Identifier = '" + message.Identifier.ToString() + "', " + "@AmazonMessageID = '" + message.AmazonMessageID + "', " + "@Status = " + ((int)message.Status).ToString() + ", " + "@ToEmailAddress = '" + message.To.Address + "', " + "@CreatedDate = '" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + "'\n";
                        //logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage( ",\t" + message.ash_BatchLoopCounter + "-" + message.ash_BatchSizeCount +  ",\t" + response.SendEmailResult.MessageId + ",\t" + message.QueueMessageId, true);//ASH-TEST 11Jan14
                        lock (statLocker)
                        {
                            if (response != null) amazonMessageID = response.SendEmailResult.MessageId;
                            if (message.ash_isSent == "DUPLICATE") { return; }
                        }
                        //logManager_CollectionLog.LogMessage("\tSendSimpleEmail\t-\t" + message.ash_BatchSizeCount + "-" + message.ash_BatchLoopCounter + "\t-\t" + message.QueueMessageId, true);//ASH-TEST 10Jan14                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SendRawEmailResponse response = SendRawEmail(message);
                        lock (statLocker)
                        {
                            if (response != null) amazonMessageID = response.SendRawEmailResult.MessageId;
                            intCounter += 1;//ASH-TEST 10Jan14
                            logManager_MessageLog.LogMessage("\tSendRawEmail-1" + intCounter + "\t-\t" + amazonMessageID + "\t-\t" + message.QueueMessageId, true);//ASH-TEST 10Jan14
                        }
                    }
                    lock (statLocker)
                    {
                        message.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                        toUpdate.Add(message, message.UpdateStatus(amazonMessageID == string.Empty ? MessageStatus.Tested : MessageStatus.Sent,
                                                                    "", null, null, true));
                        messageCount++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("blacklist")
                     || ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("rejected")
                     || ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("not verified")
                     || ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("illegal")
                        //|| message.OldStatus == MessageStatus.Failed)
                     || message.Status == MessageStatus.Failed)
                    {
                        toUpdate.Add(message, message.UpdateStatus(MessageStatus.Undeliverable, ex.Message, null, null, true));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toUpdate.Add(message, message.UpdateStatus(MessageStatus.Failed, ex.Message, null, null, true));
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToLower());//ASH22Nov
                }
                lock (statLocker)
                {
                    StatisticKey key = new StatisticKey(Convert.ToInt32(message.ash_campaignHistoryID), Convert.ToInt32(message.ash_campaignTemplateID), message.Status);//ASH25,OCT13//Airmail 2.0 changes
                    if (!statistics.ContainsKey(key)) statistics.Add(key, 0);
                    statistics[key]++;
                }
            });
            lock (dbLocker)
            {
                //cSH12Jan14-test//messageRepository.ash_Log_SentMessageids(sqlLogSentMessage);//ASH12Jan14
                try
                {
                    Task UpdateMessages_Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => messageRepository.ash_UpdateMessages(toUpdate), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                    UpdateMessages_Task.Wait();//ASH18Sep2013 - This task added for updating message asynchronously
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logManager_RunSummary.LogException(ex);
                }
                if (activeThreadCount > maxNoofTaskCount)//targetThreadCount
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                if (abort)
                {
                    sendComplete = true;
                    return 1;
                }
                try
                {
                    if (messageBatch == null && messageBatch.Count == 0)
                    {
                        messageBatch = messageRepository.ash_GetNextBatch_AirmailVer2(maxBatchSize, this.senderTrackingHost);//messageBatch = messageRepository.ash_GetNextBatch(maxBatchSize);
                    }
                    else { messageBatch = null; }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logManager_RunSummary.LogException(ex);
                    messageBatch = new List<Airmail.Core.Message>();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(this.currentStatus);
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: That is *a lot* of code, and I don't think anyone is prepared to dig through all that. Could you maybe narrow your problem down to a small snippet? It would also help if you could make your problem description clearer: I have a hard time understanding what you wall of code is *supposed* to do, what it's *actually* doing, and what you've *tried* to do. Also, this belongs on [so], not on [programmers.se].

Comment: Hi Amon, please see the small snippet of code here                 try
                {
Parallel.ForEach(messageAmazonRequestBatch.Distinct<Message_withRequest>(),
                        n =>
                        {
                                Message_withRequest n2 = n;
                                var amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(n2.req);
                                n2.msg.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID;
                                
                        }
                     );

Comment: That's a big amount of code to read through, could you [simplify the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it's easier to read, but still demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having issue that happens when you combine loop constructs and lambda expressions. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp). Cleanest way to fix it is to create an object, that represents the thread set it's parameters and start it. Or you can just create local copies of all variables you are using as suggested in the previous link.

Comment: Hi Euphonic, I read the post you suggested and to avoid the issue, i declared the local variable. Still the duplicate issue happens. See here... Parallel.ForEach(messageAmazonRequestBatch.Distinct<Message_withRequest>(), n => { Message_withRequest n2 = n; var amazonMessageID = SendSimpleEmail_Part2(n2.req); n2.msg.AmazonMessageID = amazonMessageID; }

Comment: @user3241488 The variable is supposed to be OUTSIDE the lambda. But when I look at it this shouldn't be problem with Parallel.ForEach. Are you sure the duplicates are not in "messageAmazonRequestBatch"?

Comment: Yes, not all messages are duplicate only a couple of them so say 1-2 %  and i am sure there are no duplicates in that batch.